# Windows magnifier shortcut in windows server 2012

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2

In Windows 10, Windows magnifier works with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>alt</kbd>+ mouse scroll.

But it doesnt works with the same keys in windows server 2012. Any idea to make it work as in windows 10?

As you can see below, on Windows 10:

[image]

EDIT:

This is the auto hotkey code that can be used to achieve ctrl+alt+MouseWheel on Windows Server but Since <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> is also the shortcut key to open Windows Magnifier, it opens up magnifiers inside Remote Sessions which makes it very laggy.

```
^!WheelUp::SendInput, #{NumpadAdd}
^!WheelDown::SendInput, #{NumpadSub}
```

Comment: I also try to use the magnifier both on the windows 10 and windows server 2012, and the keyboard shortcut ctrl +alt + mouse scroll didn't work on the windows server 2012, too. I think it could be not supported on the windows server 2012,  or it is disable by default.

Answer (score 1):

The magnifier works fine for me on Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials using
the shortcut <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

You might be missing some system features. I have the following installed which
might apply :

- User Interfaces and Infrastructure

  - Graphical Management Tools and Infrastructure
  - Server Graphical Shell

Comment: Windows and +/- is working. But I want ctrl+alt+mouse_wheel. The way it works in Windows 10.

Comment: You may map these using [AutoHotkey](https://autohotkey.com/). For some examples see [post1](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/66355-how-to-bind-the-mouse-wheel-to-keystroke/) and [post2](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/84309-biding-keys-to-mouse-wheel/). If still in doubt the persons on the AutoHotkey forums are pretty helpful.

Comment: Thanks harry. This looks good. I'll come and update if I find a solution.

Comment: got the auto hotkey hack. But unfortunately the windows magnifier shortcut hotkey is making life miserable. Code updated in question.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Auto Hotkey as suggested by @harrymc I achieved the same windows 10 like hotkeys on Windows Server 2012.

```
^!WheelUp::SendInput, #{NumpadAdd}
^!WheelDown::SendInput, #{NumpadSub}
```

Though it works perfect on host system, it opens up magnifiers when zooming in on RDP client windows operating systems as well.

So I'm looking to disable Magnifier on Remote Machines.